# Samsung Phone Keeps asking to Allow MTP every time i connect via USB

Tags: samsung, mtp

I have noticed a very annoying bug. I have noticed it on many Ubuntu versions, and also on all my Samsung Sevices. (Galaxy S4, S5, and S7). Every time i connect the phone to USB, i get a popup on the phone that asks me to "Allow access to device data" and i have to click Allow. On Windows machines, this popup appears only once, and then Windows memorizes the option for that device. You dont need to "allow" if you plug the phone back to the PC. On Ubuntu, it asks me to Allow every single time. So annoying.

Comment: This is by design and furthermore the key here is " i get a popup on the phone"  The  popup isn't generated by Ubuntu but by the phone, so off topic here.